# Possible images of $\mathbb P^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be the blow up of $\mathbb P^2$ at one point.  Does there exist a nonconstant map $\mathbb P^2 \to X$?

Comment: Here's a question that might help. Suppose I have a map $\mathbb P^2 \to \mathbb P^N$. What dimensions can the image have?

Comment: $0$ or $2$.  It is the possibility of the latter that is not clear to me; why can't there be a surjective map to $X$?

Comment: Okay, great; it wasn't clear to me from the question. I just came here to suggest intersection numbers but this has been done! It would be nice to find a way that doesn't use them, though.

Comment: If you don't want to use intersection numbers, you can use the fact that $X$ admits a map to $\mathbb{P}^1$ with $\mathbb{P}^1$ as its fibers. Then, we take the composition $\mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$. It is necessarily constant so the image is contained in a fiber, but the fibers are also all copies of $\mathbb{P}^1$, so the original map $\mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow X$ is constant.

Comment: @Dtseng Ah, it's the graph of projection from a point. Very cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there can be such a map. Suppose $\phi:\mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow X$ is a map. We divide our work into two cases.

Case 1: $\deg(\phi)>0$. In this case, $\phi$ is surjective. Let $E\in X$ be the exceptional divisor and $L\in X$ be a line disjoint from $E$. Then, $\phi^{*}E$ and $\phi^{*}L$ are divisors on $\mathbb{P}^2$ such that their intersection number is 0.

This means either $\phi^{*}E$ or $\phi^{*}L$ is trivial by Bezout's theorem. However, this is impossible since they are nontrivial divisors (this is where we use $\phi$ is surjective).

Case 2: $\deg(\phi)=0$. In this case, if $\phi$ is nonconstant, its image is a curve $C\subset X$. Since $\mathbb{P}^2$ is irreducible, $C$ is irreducible. Since $\mathbb{P}^2$ is reduced, the map $\mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow X$ factors through $C$, so we have a surjective map $\mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow C$ onto an irreducible curve.

Since $\mathbb{P}^2$ is normal, this map factors through the normalization $\tilde{C}\rightarrow C$, so we have a map $\mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow \tilde{C}$ onto a smooth curve. Any smooth curve admits a map to $\mathbb{P}^1$, so we have a surjective map $\mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$, which is impossible.

Comment: I guess you don't need intersection numbers, right? One-dimensional things in $\mathbb P^2$ have to meet.

Comment: Yeah, I think that works. We can replace the use of intersection numbers with just whether the set theoretic intersection is empty.

Comment: Could you explain why $\deg(\phi)>0$ implies that $\phi$ is surjective, and why $\deg(\phi)=0$ plus $\phi$ non-constant implies that the image is a curve $C\subseteq X$? I realize these are basic questions. (The rest of your answer was perfectly clear to me).

Comment: So for the part $\text{deg}(\phi)>0$ implies that $\phi$ is surjective, I assume it is because $\dim\mathbb{P}^{2} = \dim X$. So somehow a map of positive degree between projective varieties of the same dimension must be surjective?

Comment: Given $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ between two integral varieties of the same dimension, then $\phi$ is dominant if and only if the generic point of $Y$ is in the image. (If $X$ is proper, then being dominant implies being surjective.) Then, $[K(X):K(Y)]$ is an extension of fields. Since $K(X)$ is finitely generated as a ring over $K(Y)$, Hilber Nullstellensatz implies it is actually a finite extension. Then, $\deg(\phi)$ is defined to be the degree of the extension. If $\phi$ is not dominant, then $\deg(\phi)$ is defined to be zero.

Comment: Also, if we are working over $\mathbb{C}$ and $X$ and $Y$ are smooth and compact, the notion of degree defined above coincides with the degree of $X\rightarrow Y$ as a map of smooth, real manifolds, in which case positive degree implies surjectivity.